# Are spectra determined by their homotopy groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

A famous theorem of Whitehead essentially states that spaces are determined by their homotopy groups. Is this true for spectra too?, i.e,
$$
\text{question: is a spectrum $E$ determined by its homotopy groups $\pi_*E$?}
$$

Comment: I would argue that "spaces are determined by their homotopy groups" is a bad summary of Whiteheads theorem.  It is ambiguous, and one way of resolving the ambiguity is (very) false!   It is true that a map of spectra inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb Z$ is a weak equivalence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your statement of Whitehead's theorem is highly misleading.  It is very easy to have inequivalent based spaces $X$ and $Y$ with $\pi_*(X)\simeq\pi_*(Y)$, and the same is true for spectra.  For example, the spectra $KU$ and $\bigvee_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\Sigma^{2n}H\mathbb{Z}$ are inequivalent but have isomorphic homotopy (even as rings, if we give both spectra their usual ring structure).  However, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a map of spectra that induces an isomorphism $\pi_*(X)\to\pi_*(Y)$, then $f$ is an equivalence.  The status of this statement depends somewhat on your framework of definitions.  If we use orthogonal spectra with their usual model structure (or any similar framework), then it is a definition that $f$ is an equivalence if $\pi_*(f)$ is an isomorphism.  It is a theorem that if $X$ and $Y$ are bifibrant and $f\colon X\to Y$ is an equivalence then there is a morphism $g\colon Y\to X$ and paths joining $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ to the respective identity maps in the relevant spaces of morphisms of orthogonal spectra.  This is essentially the same as the case with spaces, where one needs to assume that $X$ and $Y$ have the homotopy type of a CW complex.